# Which Dynamic Management View exposes network traffic from/to one SPID?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2, network-traffic

I need to determine how much network traffic is being sent between a SQL Server 2008 R2 Dev Edition and an Ado.Net client running Win 7. I thought there should be a Dynamic Management View, but somehow I cannot find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sys.dm_exec_connections`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181509.aspx):

> - `num_reads`  Number of packet reads that have occurred over this
>     connection. Is nullable.
> - `num_writes` Number of data packet writes that
>     have occurred over this connection. Is nullable.
>     ...
> - `net_packet_size` Network packet size used for information and data transfer. Is
>     nullable.